# How does count distinct work in Apache spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to count distinct number of entities at different date ranges.

I need to understand how spark performs this operation

```
val distinct_daily_cust_12month = sqlContext.sql(s"select distinct day_id,txn_type,customer_id from ${db_name}.fact_customer where day_id>='${start_last_12month}' and day_id<='${start_date}' and txn_type not in (6,99)")

val category_mapping = sqlContext.sql(s"select * from datalake.category_mapping");

val daily_cust_12month_ds =distinct_daily_cust_12month.join(broadcast(category_mapping),distinct_daily_cust_12month("txn_type")===category_mapping("id")).select("category","sub_category","customer_id","day_id")

daily_cust_12month_ds.createOrReplaceTempView("daily_cust_12month_ds")

val total_cust_metrics = sqlContext.sql(s"""select 'total' as category,
count(distinct(case when day_id='${start_date}' then customer_id end)) as yest,
count(distinct(case when day_id>='${start_week}' and day_id<='${end_week}' then customer_id end)) as week,
count(distinct(case when day_id>='${start_month}' and day_id<='${start_date}' then customer_id end)) as mtd,
count(distinct(case when day_id>='${start_last_month}' and day_id<='${end_last_month}' then customer_id end)) as ltd,
count(distinct(case when day_id>='${start_last_6month}' and day_id<='${start_date}' then customer_id end)) as lsm,
count(distinct(case when day_id>='${start_last_12month}' and day_id<='${start_date}' then customer_id end)) as ltm
from daily_cust_12month_ds
""")
```

No Errors, But this is taking a lot of time. I want to know if there is a better way to do this in Spark

Answer (score 3):

Count distinct works by hash-partitioning the data and then counting distinct elements by partition and finally summing the counts. In general it is a heavy operation due to the full shuffle and there is no silver bullet to that in Spark or most likely any fully distributed system, operations with *distinct* are inherently difficult to solve in a distributed system.

In some cases there are faster ways to do it:

- If approximate values are acceptable, [`approx_count_distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#approx_count_distinct-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) will usually be much faster as it is based on [HyperLogLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) and the amount of data to be shuffled is much much less than with the exact implementation.
- If you can design your pipeline in a way that the data source is already partitioned so that there can't be any duplicates between partitions, the slow step of hash-partitioning the data frame is not needed.

P.S. To understand how count distinct work, you can always use `explain`:

```
df.select(countDistinct("foo")).explain()
```

Example output:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[count(distinct foo#3)])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
   +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(distinct foo#3)])
      +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[foo#3], functions=[])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(foo#3, 200)
            +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[foo#3], functions=[])
               +- LocalTableScan [foo#3]
```

Comment: Thanks ollik1. I guess I cant tune it further. Also when I use explain or toDebugString, the plan is often displayed truncated with "...", Is there a way I can view complete plan